# Chapter heading with the word "chapter" replaced by chapter name

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters

When I create a chapter

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\begin{document}
\chapterstyle{veelo}
\chapter{Implementation}
\section{Implementation2}
\end{document}
```

It displays it like

```
Chapter 1
Implementation
```

How can I make it display

```
Implementation 1
```

I tried doing this

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
```

But it just hides the word chapter and does display implementation and 1 in the same line.

Comment: With memoir there are several chapter styles already defined. See in the documentation; for example, `crosshead` and `culver` are similar to your request.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I want to stick to using veelo style though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following minimal example provides a solution to your problem. It modifies the `\chapter` header printing macros to print the chapter title in place of the chapter name (`Chapter` or `\@chapapp`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx (required with veelo chapter style)
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\chs@veelo{%
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}[1]{%
    \chapnamefont\MakeUppercase{#1}}% Changed \@chapapp to #1; could also use \chaptitlefont
  \let\printchaptertitle\@gobble% Remove printing of chapter title.
}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}% <cmd>
  {\printchaptername}% <search>
  {\printchaptername{#1}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%\tableofcontents
\chapterstyle{veelo}
\chapter{Implementation}
\section{Implementation2}
\end{document}
```

The `veelo` chapter style is stored in `\chs@veelo`, which defines the style in which the chapter title is printed. Appending (via `\g@addto@macro`) a renewed definition of `\printchaptername` (which now takes an argument), it replaces the former `\@chapapp` printing. If you want to maintain the former chapter title font, this can be modified to set it using `\chaptitlefont`. Additionally, the functionality of `\printchaptertitle` is removed (setting it to `\@gobble`).

`\@makechapterhead` actually sets the chapter heading. So, [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) is used to patch it and insert the newly created `\printchaptername` to take the supplied argument `#1`.

Comment: Why not simply copy the `veelo` code from `memoir.cls` and make your own `myveelo`, that might be alightly easier than figuring out hos to patch the code (and figure out how it is stored internally)